# AngularJS, I have a function when I ran it, I got unauthorized 401

Tags: angularjs, authentication, spring-boot, unauthorized

I have a problem with a function, when I ran it I got error:

> PUT http://10.10.3.20:8082/oct/activite/updateStatus/4 401 ()
>
> error_description
> :
> "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

this is my function in back-end with spring boot:

service:

```
@Override
public boolean MajStatus(Long id) {
    Activite ac = activiteRepository.findOne(id);
    ac.setStateActivite(true);
    activiteRepository.saveAndFlush(ac);
    return true;
}
```

ctrl:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_manager","ROLE_validateur"})
@RequestMapping(value="/updateStatus/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public boolean MajStatus(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return activiteMetier.MajStatus(id);
}
```

in front-end I use AngularJS
ctrl:

```
    $scope.MajStatus = function (index) {

    var authorization = "Bearer " + $sessionStorage.get('access_token');
    var config22 = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authorization
        }
    };
    
    $scope.activiteStatus={};
    
    $http.put(prod.url3+"/activite/updateStatus/"+index,config22)
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.activiteStatus = response;
        $state.reload();
        SweetAlert.swal({
            title: 'Status expired',
            text: 'I will close in 2 seconds.',
            timer: 2000
        });
    })
    .error(function(response){
        $scope.data = response.statusText;
    });
    
    return $scope.activiteStatus;
};
```

in my page html:

```
<td ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); MajStatus(p.idActivite)" 
ng-if="p.stateActivite==false" class="hidden-xs">
<span class="label label-sm label-success">Active</span></td>
```

I have problem just with this function, other functions of CRUD works fine and I'm in connect with user that have ROLE_manager.

I did test the function in back-end using 'Advanced REST client' and it works fine.
The problem is in front-end. So please I need your help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think the service you consume is secured and I dont think you are calling with the proper authentication

Comment: I don't know spring, so this could be normal. However, you appear to have the route `"/updateStatus/{id}"` but are calling `/activite/updateStatus/id` - is your route correct? the additional `activate` doesn't appear to be part of it.

Comment: @CrazyMac the service secured with ROLE_manager and I'm connect with it so it's not the problem.

Comment: @Darren I use @RequestMapping(value="/activite") global in back-end so it's the same in back and front :)

Comment: @RagnarLodbrok Did you test this service through postman or any httpclient to verify this service is not expecting any special headers. If it works there with the same headers then we can think of

Comment: @CrazyMac yes I did test it with "Advanced REST client" and it works fine

Comment: @RagnarLodbrok From the message it looks like the app is expecting an authentication, check your config files to see if you have any security being set. If you are using maven, check if you have included any spring security items

Comment: @CrazyMac the problem of this function is in front-end angularjs and not in back-end coz all others functions work fine, just this one who's not working !!